# What kind of values might the debug parameter of visitSource in ASM ClassVisitor receive?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

The visitCode method in asm's ClassVisitor accepts a debug parameter typed as a String

```
public final void visitSource(final String file, final String debug)
```

According to the JavaDoc

> debug - additional debug information to compute the correspondance
>   between source and compiled elements of the class. May be null.

I don't believe I've ever seen this populated with a value apart from null.

Under what circustances will this value be populated?

What does the data it contains look like?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `http://mail.ow2.org/wws/info/asm`

Comment: @Shark Yes, probably more chance of an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debug` value goes into the `SourceDebugExtension` class file attribute. You can find a complete description of its contents in [JSR-045](http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/review/jsr045/).

Usually it is used to support debugging non-Java source code compiled into Java classes, for example - JSPs. If I am not mistaken, JRuby also populating it when generating Java classes.

Comment: That link seems to return a 404 now. I believe this is the new link: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=045